# Java 8 - JTextField hanging when setText several times

Tags: java

I have simple code to test:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class TitledBorderTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public TitledBorderTest()
    {
        jbInit();
    }

    /** Parameter panel*/
    private JPanel northPanel = new JPanel();

    private JTextField tfInfo = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton bSearch = new JButton("Click here");

    public void jbInit()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300,200));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));

        tfInfo.setEditable(false);
        tfInfo.setFont(new Font("",Font.BOLD, 11));
        tfInfo.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        //
        tfInfo.setOpaque(false);
        tfInfo.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Title here")); 
        //
        bSearch.addActionListener(this);
        northPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        northPanel.add(tfInfo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        northPanel.add(bSearch, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == bSearch) cmd_search();
    }

    public void cmd_search()
    {
        (new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                loadData();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void loadData()
    {   
        bSearch.setEnabled(false);
        //
        int count = 0;
        tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
        tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
        tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
        tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
        tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
        tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
        tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
        tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
        //
        bSearch.setEnabled(true);
    }

    /**
     * Main test
     * @param arg
     */
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        TitledBorderTest tbt = new TitledBorderTest();
        tbt.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

When run this code, I click the button "click here" (sometimes click 2,3 ... times), I don't know why my app hanging at this code:

```
public void loadData()
{   
    .....
    tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
    tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
    tfInfo.setText("setText Count: " + (++count));
    .....
}
```

I found that when i remove one of 2 lines, this error doest not appear (may be it not hanging again)

```
public void jbInit()
    {
        ......

        // remove one of 2 lines -> my app not hanging
        tfInfo.setOpaque(false);
        tfInfo.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Title here")); 

        .....
    }
```

When I debug into JTextField.setText() method, it hanging on TitledBorder getFont() ...

This occurs on java 1.8_101 only (when I test on java 1.6, this issue does not occur).

Please help me? thanks :(

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a Thread to update the state of the text field or button.

Swing components should be updated on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.

Code from an listener automatically executes on the EDT so you don't need to do anything special, just invoke your method.